please suggest me a good free video editing software for windows
Please suggest to me a good free video editing software for windows in which I can put multiple markers on a video (audio included) so that I can easily remember important parts to take/edit from a video?
By markers I meant something to mark certain portion on a video during editing. Suppose I have a 5 min video from which I need to remove unwanted portions and keep only important portions, so when I’m watching and listening to the video on that software, I get first important portion 2min to 2min30s , so I put 2 markers on 2min and 2m30s then I continue to watch next portion of video to find another important portion. Like that, I found 2 more important portions 3m-4m15s and 4m-4m25s, so I give 4 markers on those too.
also i should be able to easily recognize/differentiate between a marked/labeled important portion from an unmarked unimportant portion just by viewing the track diagram without needing to play each video portion, like important marked portions are of different color than unmarked portins or I could only select important portion by single mouse click but cant select unimportant portion by single mouse click or could add tags to those important portions.  It's like lebel track in Audacity .
Then using the software's a certain feature I can keep only marked regions and remove all other unimportant portions from that video easily by single/few clicks.
i want to mark segment like this-


The built in ClipChamp for Windows 10+ is pretty decent and does that clipping and cropping on audio and video.
I use it for simple things all the time.

I have also tried a couple from this list https://obsproject.com/wiki/Post-Production-Tools-you-can-use
OpenShot is decent, simple, free/ open source and does what you need.
I have also used XSplit for simple cutting of existing clips to down to smaller bits - for example if you use OBS screen recording and simply want to crop the video and audio to a shorter length.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
